# Defining a class member with a class type defined later in C++

Tags: c++

Like I would want to do something like this,

```
class Object {
public:
World * Parent_World; //This here
Object(World * Parent_World=NULL) : Parent_World(Parent_World) {}
};

class World {
public:
Object * Objects = new Object[100];
}
```

That doesn't work because of the order.
And I can't just simply define world earlier because I want also to have access to class Object from the World

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a forward declaration before Object:

```
class World; //Now you can use pointers and references to World
class Object {
public:
World * Parent_World; //This here
Object(World * Parent_World=NULL) : Parent_World(Parent_World) {}
};

class World {
public:
Object * Objects = new Object[100];
}
```

Making a forward declaration gives a compiler enough information to deal with pointers and references to the type being declared

Answer (score 1):

Andrew's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11144968/383402) has it right: you need a forward declaration.

It's worth noting, however, that you can't use a forward declaration when the compiler must know the size of the object. That means your `World*` member will work, but a `World` member would not.

Answer (score 0):

forward declare your class like this:

```
   class World;
```

This works if you only use pointers to World until the World class is defined.

Comment: This works only if you use it in a context where an incomplete type is allowed, would be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put

```
class World;
```

before

```
class Object { ... }
```

This is called [forward declaration](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/forward_decl.html).